# Modifying element of 2d array is condition met matlab

Tags: matlab

i want to replace the element of array BW with element of array 'a' when element of BW is zero.
Here is the code i have written

`for i=0:row`
    `for j=0:col`
         `if BW(i,j)==0`
            `BW(i,j)=a(i,j);`
      `end`
    end
    end

i get error for  if BW(i,j)=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way is:

```
BW(find(BW == 0)) = a(i,j)
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for the loop.

Index the zero elements in `BW` then replace with corresponding element in `a`

```
idx = BW == 0;
BW(idx) = a(idx);
```

This solution assumes that `a` is at least as big as `BW`